# I am unable to create Microsoft Azure Subscription

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, cloud, roles, subscription

Though I am a global administrator for my organization.
Whenever I try to create a new subscription, the portal says "(Select an Offer for your subscription)".

[Azure Subscription Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1U0L.jpg)
[image]

I am trying to create a new subscription but I am unable to create one.

Comment: What error are you getting when you choose the 'Pay-As-You-Go' option, which is the most common choice?

Comment: **I was able to find a solution** .

If you have only the EA Admin role, you won’t be able to create subscriptions by default, you also need the EA account owner role.

In order to create, activate & register your account as owner — follow this [MS Learn Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/direct-ea-administration#add-an-account-and-account-owner)